# Isotypic projector for reductive group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ a complex representation. Recall that for an irreducible character $\chi$, the $\chi$-isotypic component $V[\chi]$ is the image of the $\chi$-isotypic projector
$$
P_{\chi}:=\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\overline{\chi(g)}\rho(g),
$$
and $V=\bigoplus_{\chi} V[\chi]$. $V[\chi]$ is characterized as the unique subrepresentation of $V$ such that every irreducible subrepresentation of it is isomorphic to the irreducible representation $W$ of $G$ with character $\chi$.

More generally, if $ G $ is a compact Lie group then there is still a decomposition into isotypic components $V=\bigoplus_{\chi} V[\chi]$ but now the projector is given by
$$
P_{\chi}:=\frac{\chi(1)}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\overline{\chi(g)}\rho(g),
$$
where now the sum denotes an integral over the compact group $ G $ with respect to the haar measure.

What about non-compact groups? When is there still an isotypic decomposition? Can the isotypic projectors still be constructed as above? Do we need something else like assuming that the noncompact group is reductive or that the representation is unitary?

Comment: Important to note that, apart from trivial cases, no finite dimensional rep of a non-compact non-abelian reductive group will be unitary. Of course if we assume our group is semisimple then any finite dimensional rep splits into irreps which can then be combined to give you an isotypic decomp. This is not true of reductive groups in general (although the adjoint rep would still work for them)